# GROUP BY chat_id - Return only if rows of all criteria are matched

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of chat participants that looks like this:

```
id         chat_id          participant_id
1          1                5
2          1                7
3          1                9
```

If the user creates a new chat, we first want to make sure a chat with the requested participants does not already exist, if it does we will just use that chat.

So here let's say I want to create a chat with the participants `5`, `7`, `9`, and `11`.

In this case, nothing would be returned and a new chat with a new `chat_id` would have to be created, since there is no chat that contains all of these members.

However, if we want to create a chat with just participants `5`, `7`, and `9`, the `chat_id` of `1` should be returned.

Is there an efficient way to structure a query to achieve this without using loops?

I tried something like this but never got desired results:

```
SELECT chat_id FROM chat_participants WHERE participant IN(5,7,9) GROUP BY chat_id
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add condition with count of your requested participants total like this

```
SELECT chat_id FROM chat_participants WHERE participant IN(5,7,9) GROUP 
BY chat_id having count(chat_id) = 3
```

if you pass like `IN(5,7,9,11)` than your condition will be  `having count(chat_id) = 4`

Comment: Assumes participant can't be listed multiple times in a chat but a fair assumption.  (if we had 5,7,7) you'd treat it as a match when it may not be.  but adding distinct to having count is overhead if that situation can't exist.

Comment: @xQbert  yes if he/she add duplicate participant id he/she has to mange count and what is missing i am updating

Comment: I wouldn't update.  The assumption is a fair one to make and the distinct will degrade performance.  Just wanted DanL to be aware of the assumption; and how to fix if the assumption was bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
select chat_id
from
(
select chat_id, group_concat(participant order by participant, ',') as gc
from chat_participants
where chat id in (select chat_id from chat_participants where participant IN(5,7,9))
group by chat_id 
) x1
where x1.gc = '5,7,9'
```

Comment: may be you also need to add order by participant